# Laptop Stuck on screen with displayed GRUB

Tags: grub2

Long story short:

1. I had Ubuntu 22.04 on my laptop. I could boot different operation systems and successfully install them.
2. I wanted to try out Debian 12. Everything works cool but I didn't like it.
3. Now I want to boot Ubuntu and what I see on the screen is this:
   [image]
   The same is happening with Linux Mint, ProxMox...
4. If I plugin usb with Debian everything works fine I am able to boot it and install it.
   [image]

Trying to fix this sh*t for more than a week now...
Any idea what could this be and what am I doing wrong?
Thank you all.

Comment: You can refer https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2021-December/041769.html which Ubuntu carries patches to reverse (*so Ubuntu detects other OSes on your computer by default, Debian does not thus doesn't detect your prior Ubuntu system, just reverse the default of os-prober and it will detect Ubuntu*)

Comment: Your specific details are unclear; you mention many OSes with Debian 12 the only one mentioned clearly; thus prior comment relates to the change (from upstream) which Ubuntu carries patches to revert (*other OSes do not*). I'd make Debian detect other OSes (*modify os-prober default*), then boot your Ubuntu system, and make it take ownership of the boot process (*`grub-install`; ownership is usually the last installed OS; if Debian was last - that'll be it; how you installed Debian will influence this though, Debian having two installers available, but we don't support Debian here*).

Comment: Thank you for your answers guys.
I am adding OS with details, which I tried:
- Ubuntu 22.04 LTS,
- Linux Mint 20,
- ProxMox VE 8.0.

Comment: I still don't understand how I am supposed to fix the issue.

Comment: I would boot Debian (*given that's an OS you can currently boot*), modify it's os-prober config (I'd use `vim` but whatever editor you can noting you'l need elevated privileges) & then `update-grub`. You should then have options to boot other OSes on other drive(s) or partition(s).  Reboot & select the one you want to own the booting; then make it take ownership of the boot process (`grub-install` should do this for Ubuntu with `update-grub` to ensure all known OSes are updated correctly). The `grub-install` will require device name that matches your machine BIOS/uEFI setup.